# Passing outside variables to MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, function, variables, matlab-guide

My program loads data from a file and produces a graph, the user clicks on an area of interest and then analysis is done and a new graph is produced. The program continues asking the user to click on the image until the user presses `e` to exit the program.

I want the graph that is produced to be a GUI that takes data from my program but I seem to have trouble transferring that data into the GUI function. Here is a quick example of what my program looks like:

```
load(data)
plot(x,y)
while 1%so that it continues asking for user interaction
     figure(1)
     'click on the point you want or press e to exit'
     [x1,y1,key]=ginput(1)

     f=score(x1,y1)
     %the above is a different function that gives us the data that I want to graph,
     %that are called xf,yf 

     %GUI plot
     figure(1)
     test_gui(xf,yf)

     if (key == 'e')
     display('End')
     break;
     else
     display('next point')
     end
end
```

My `test_gui.m` looks like this:

```
function varargout = test_gui(varargin)
% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
               'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
               'gui_OpeningFcn', @test_gui_OpeningFcn, ...
               'gui_OutputFcn',  @test_gui_OutputFcn, ...
               'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
               'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before fft_guide is made visible.
function test_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)


% Choose default command line output for test_gui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes test_gui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = test_gui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
plot (xf,yf)
```

The problem is that when I click on the "Push" button, it does not graph anything so there must be something wrong in the way I pass the `xf`, `yf` variables. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas about what I am doing wrong, I have not used GUIDE before and it seems I'm lost.

Comment: You should implement the loop on the gui start-up function, inside the gui implementation, not outside. There are many ways to store xf and yf, but the recommended by matlab is to do that by using the `handles` variable. I cannot help you now with more details, but you could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339335/how-to-create-a-gui-to-play-pause-fast-forward-and-rewind-video-in-matlab/18341693#18341693) to see an example of gui implementation which I explain exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your code, `xf` and `yf` are never defined, only `f` (the result of `score`). So that could be why you can't see any plots.

Supposing that `score` dumps `xf` and `yf` into the workspace, you must first define them from `varargin` and then pass them to the callback function using `handles`, as Werner commented.

```
% --- Executes just before fft_guide is made visible.
function test_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
xf = varargin{0}; yf = varargin{1}; % Get xf and yf from input
handles.xf = xf; handles.yf = yf;  % Put the values in handles
guidata(hObject,handles);   % Save handles so you can use it anywhere in the GUI
```

And in the callback:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
plot (handles.xf,handles.yf)
```

I believe this should work, supposing `xf` and `yf` are being correctly define before being passed to the GUI function.

Comment: Thank you very much. You guessed right I had xf,yf in my workspace (I just did not include it in the code i copied here) but the problem was that I had not included xf = varargin{1}; yf = varargin{2};. Once I included this line it worked great! Thank you again!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. If you are satisfied with your results, please accept my answer by clicking the green tick. ;)